# I want to add firebase dependency

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

Please which firebase dependency will allow me to use the firebase method  `mFireBaseRef = new Firebase("https://MonAirtelEtMoi.firebaseio.com");` the firebase only is throwing error `not resolved`.

```
public class AddTodo extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataSetFire> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataSetFire, FirebaseViewHolder> adapter;
    DatabaseReference rootRef,demoRef;
    ListView listView;
    Firebase mRef;

    mRef = new Firebase("https://<myURL>..");
    private ArrayList<DataSetFire> arrayList;
//Important in Viewing data

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_todo);
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewfortodo);


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        rootRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ToDo");
        rootRef.keepSynced(true);
        String title= getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(view.getContext(), TodoContent.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


listView.setAdapter(new FirebaseListAdapter<com.example.guide.Populate>(this,com.example.guide.Populate.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,rootRef) {
    // Populate view as needed
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Populate populate, int position) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(populate.getTitle());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(populate.getDescription());
    }
});
    }

}
```

Please which firebase dependency will allow me to use the firebase method  `mFireBaseRef = new Firebase("https://MonAirtelEtMoi.firebaseio.com");` the firebase only is throwing error not resolved.

Comment: have you added dependencies in Gradle file?

Comment: what u want firebase real time database???

Comment: In the code mRef is throwing an error..

Comment: Firebase is underlined red

Comment: Please show your App Gradle file. and provide information required by others so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

In your root-level (project-level) Gradle file (build.gradle), add rules to include the Google Services Gradle plugin. Check that you have Google's Maven repository, as well.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
// Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
google()  // Google's Maven repository
}

dependencies {
// ...

// Add the following line:
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
 // ...

 repositories {
 // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
 google()  // Google's Maven repository
 // ...
  }
}
```

In your module (app-level) Gradle file (usually app/build.gradle), apply the Google Services Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add the following line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

 android {
  // ...
 }
```

Comment: STILL THROWING ERROR